# перекрывание svg-объектов

Tags: css, svg, svg-animation

Код svg-картинки:

```
<svg
     width="100%"
     height="111.14265mm"
     version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 90.971069 111.14265"
     id="svg97"      
    <g
       id="g994">
      <rect
         x="8.2400427"
         y="6.3651724"
         width="23.72028"
         height="98.379417"
         fill="#ffe7e7"
         stroke="#000006"
         stroke-width="0.506255"
         id="rect36"
         style="stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
      <rect
         transform="scale(-1)"
         x="-30.615013"
         y="-63.247421"
         width="1.8641548"
         height="8.3404837"
         fill="url(#radialGradient151593)"
         stroke-width="0.284019"
         id="rect69"
         style="fill:url(#radialGradient151593);stroke:#8a6e3e;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
      <rect
         x="10.144035"
         y="9.4162321"
         width="16.67684"
         height="91.080803"
         fill="url(#radialGradient153802)"
         stroke-width="0.80874"
         id="rect73"
         style="fill:url(#radialGradient153802);stroke:#8a6e3e;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
    </g>
   
    <g
       fill="#f8f6d3"
       stroke-width="0"
       id="g91"
       transform="matrix(0.53258521,0,0,0.46019001,-11.02889,-13.461654)">
      <path
         d="M 181.87,149.95 V 43.74 h 7.6717 V 256.16 H 181.87 Z"
         id="path81" />
      <path
         d="m 144.36,43.423 c 6.1226,-0.06739 16.007,-0.06731 21.966,1.55e-4 5.9586,0.06748 0.94926,0.12261 -11.132,0.12252 -12.081,-8.7e-5 -16.956,-0.05528 -10.834,-0.12268 z"
         id="path83" />
      <path
         d="m 22.696,36.491 v -5.5451 h 166.85 v 11.09 H 22.696 Z"
         id="path85" />
      <path
         d="M 22.696,149.95 V 43.74 h 8.4124 V 256.16 H 22.696 Z"
         id="path87" />
      <path
         d="m 22.696,263.63 v -5.7584 h 166.85 v 11.517 H 22.696 Z"
         id="path89" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Код анимации:

```
@keyframes leftDoorRaspash{
from{
    transform: rotateY(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
50%{
    transform: rotateY(90deg) skewY(50deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
to{
    transform: rotateY(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
}

#g994{
animation-name: leftDoorRaspash;
transform-box: fill-box;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
z-index: 3;
}
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы анимируемый svg-элемент при движении перекрывал область с заливкой? С элементами `path` такой проблемы нет, там через `z-index` решается, но область с заливкой все равно перекрывает анимируемый элемент. Находятся элементы в одном слое.

Comment: Добавьте код, пожалуйста. Не весь, а только "область с заливкой" и "анимируемый элемент", который перекрывается. Ну и базовую структуру, чтобы был виден эффект, о котором вы говорите.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я просто перенес дверь (`<g id="g994">`) в конец SVG. Отрисовка то идет поочередно.

```css
@keyframes leftDoorRaspash{
    from{
        transform: rotateY(0deg) skewY(0deg);
        transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotateY(90deg) skewY(50deg);
        transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }
    to{
        transform: rotateY(0deg) skewY(0deg);
        transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    }
    }
    
    #g994{
    animation-name: leftDoorRaspash;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    z-index: 3;
    }
```

```html
<svg
    width="100%"
    height="111.14265mm"
    version="1.1"
    viewBox="0 0 90.971069 111.14265"
    id="svg97">      

    <g
        fill="#f8f6d3"
        stroke-width="0"
        id="g91"
        transform="matrix(0.53258521,0,0,0.46019001,-11.02889,-13.461654)">
        <path
            d="M 181.87,149.95 V 43.74 h 7.6717 V 256.16 H 181.87 Z"
            id="path81" />
        <path
            d="m 144.36,43.423 c 6.1226,-0.06739 16.007,-0.06731 21.966,1.55e-4 5.9586,0.06748 0.94926,0.12261 -11.132,0.12252 -12.081,-8.7e-5 -16.956,-0.05528 -10.834,-0.12268 z"
            id="path83" />
        <path
            d="m 22.696,36.491 v -5.5451 h 166.85 v 11.09 H 22.696 Z"
            id="path85" />
        <path
            d="M 22.696,149.95 V 43.74 h 8.4124 V 256.16 H 22.696 Z"
            id="path87" />
        <path
            d="m 22.696,263.63 v -5.7584 h 166.85 v 11.517 H 22.696 Z"
            id="path89" />
    </g>
        <g id="g994">
        <rect
            x="8.2400427"
            y="6.3651724"
            width="23.72028"
            height="98.379417"
            fill="#ffe7e7"
            stroke="#000006"
            stroke-width="0.506255"
            id="rect36"
            style="stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.78544" />
        <rect
            transform="scale(-1)"
            x="-30.615013"
            y="-63.247421"
            width="1.8641548"
            height="8.3404837"
            fill="url(#radialGradient151593)"
            stroke-width="0.284019"
            id="rect69"
            style="fill:url(#radialGradient151593);stroke:#8a6e3e;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
        <rect
            x="10.144035"
            y="9.4162321"
            width="16.67684"
            height="91.080803"
            fill="url(#radialGradient153802)"
            stroke-width="0.80874"
            id="rect73"
            style="fill:url(#radialGradient153802);stroke:#8a6e3e;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Я делал визуализацию шкафов на canvas. Сразу разнес элементы на слои. Нижний - комната, стены. Потом внешний корпус с радиусными полками и прочим таким. Потом внутрянку. Последним - двери. Если скрываю двери, то видно внутрянку. А так фасады всегда на виду, ведь отрисовываются последними. Хотя я и по z-index разносил. Но смысл такой же.

Comment: Про слои знаю, и как они работают, мне известно. Мне с этим надо было разобраться. А можно ли заставить элемент "отрисовываться вперед других", не перенося его в конец svg?

Comment: В моем случае слои - отдельные canvas с прозрачным фоном, которые я стопкой накладываю друг на друга. Перерисовывается только нужный слой, как в мультипликации. Ну или все по очереди. По поводу порядка отрисовки в SVG не скажу, возможно благодаря SVG-filters (feBlend?, feComposite?) - я не знаю. Должно быть, в canvas есть globalCompositeOperation для этого, ей можно подкладывать следующее под предыдущее и прочие манипуляции делать. Но с анимируемыми тоже отдельный вопрос.